# Is phpseclib ASN1 biginteger in MATH_BIGINTEGER_MODE_GMP incompatible with standard implementation?

Tags: php, biginteger, phpseclib, asn.1

I'm using phpseclib to parse Apple application manifest (for in-app purchases). 
I can parse it in c# with ASN1 library of Liping Dai and everything as expected.
Also I have two webhosts, "A" with php 5.4.45 and OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015 and "B" with php 5.5.27 OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013.

Not sure what to blame, but on host "A" phpseclib/ASN1 parses manifest from byte string as expected, while on new "B" host I've faced strange problem. All BIGINT (type=integer) values were parsed to Math_Bigint with MATH_BIGINTEGER_MODE_GMP mode (phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php). I debugged in c# and php simulateously and found that while structure is correct, int values are wrong - there were some resource values, which gave wrong int values.

I've solved it by commenting MATH_BIGINTEGER_MODE_GMP in phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php::Math_BigInteger constructor, and thus switched it to  MATH_BIGINTEGER_MODE_BCMATH mode. Now it works like on host "A". But that's looks like magic, and I hate magic in code. Did somebody bumped into this?

Comment: Can you post your phpinfo() from host "B"? Or rather, can you post it on pastebin.org and post a link? Also, do serialize() on one of the BigInteger variables from host "B" that loads correctly with MATH_BIGINTEGER_MODE_BCMATH but not MATH_BIGINTEGER_MODE_GMP and post the serialization on pastebin.org (separate link) and include that in your post as well.

Comment: sorry, I can't post the whole phpinfo because of security rules, maybe you need some particular sections from it? also I can't post original asn1 values. I thought it is a general issue -  openssl version or something similar. unfortunately, currently I have not enough time on the full investigation, Decembe deadlines, you know

Comment: Honestly, I'd say it'd be good to have the whole phpinfo() if the environment is going to reproduced as authentically as possible, but in lieu of that, I guess the GMP section. But like a few months ago phpseclib got a bug report about issues that only were apparently only issues on pre-5.3 installs on 32-bit Linux installs. So the PHP version, in and of itself, wasn't sufficient. The fact that it was Linux wasn't sufficient. You needed the PHP version, the OS /and/ you needed to know how many bits the CPU was. My point being that sometimes the issues can be due to very specific system configs

Comment: (see the release notes for the 1.0.4 release at https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/releases for more info on what I just mentioned)

Comment: W.r.t. your inability to to provide the "original asn1 values"...  well what is the ASN.1 encoded thing you're dealing with? If you're dealing with, for example, an X.509 cert, the public key portion of the cert is supposed to be public. If the numbers in the public cert demonstrate the problem it doesn't seem like providing one of them would compromise any sensitive info?